# How can I sort a column using translation file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two tables in my database.
Eu tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados.
1º test_case_statuses 
2º test_case_runs

The first table has the columns: id and identifier.
The contents of this table is this:
id  identifier
1   new
2   approved 
3   reproved

The second table has columns id e status_id.

My application is in portuguese, so I'm using a translation file.
This file has the following lines:

```
labels
   ...
   test_cases_statuses:
     new: "Novo"
     approved: "Aprovado"
  reproved: "Reprovado"
...
```

The problem is that I need to sort the contents of the table in alphabetical order.
For other columns I'm using the following code:

view/test_plan_cases

```
...

<%= sortable_th @search, :test_case_number, {}, :remote => true %>
...
```

app/helpers/

```
def sortable_th(builder = nil, attribute = nil, *args) 

# th_classes = ['green']
th_classes = []
content = nil

unless builder.nil? || attribute.nil?
  th_classes << 'header'
  content = sort_link(builder, attribute, *args)

  if content.include? 'sort_link asc'
    th_classes << 'headerSortDown'
  elsif content.include? 'sort_link desc'
    th_classes << 'headerSortUp'
  end
end

th_classes = th_classes.join(' ')
content_tag :th, content, class: th_classes
 end



def sortable_teste(builder = nil, attribute = nil, *args) 
# th_classes = ['green']
th_classes = []
content = nil

unless builder.nil? || attribute.nil?
  th_classes << 'header'
  content = sort_teste(builder, attribute, *args)

  if content.include? 'sort_teste asc'
    th_classes << 'headerSortDown'
  elsif content.include? 'sort_teste desc'
    th_classes << 'headerSortUp'
  end
end

th_classes = th_classes.join(' ')
content_tag :th, content, class: th_classes

 end
```

controller/test_case_runs_controller

```
  @search = @project.test_plan_cases.allowed_for(@release, current_user).search search_values
```

Need guidance and help to do this.
What I'm thinking of doing is to use an enumerator type to save the contents of the translation file.
Would look like this:

[1 'Novo',

2 'Aprovado',

3'Reprovado']

After that I lose myself, should create another form of ordering or would like to adapt the above code?
I appreciate any help =]

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to issue a sort on a vitual field calculated with SQL. You have to build your field definition this way:

```sql
CASE status_id
 WHEN 1 THEN ‘Novo′
 WHEN 2 THEN ‘Aprovado′
 WHEN 3 THEN ‘Reprovado′
END
```

You can then use this as an order clause:

```
@search = @project.test_plan_cases.some_other_scope.order("#{case_above} ASC")
```

and similar queries.

Comment: Thanks for answer fast o/  I tried to use this but it's not working, would stay like this:                                         `@search = @project.test_plan_cases.allowed_for(@release, current_user).search.order(
"#{
CASE status_id
 WHEN 1 THEN 'Novo'
 WHEN 2 THEN 'Aprovado'
 WHEN 3 THEN 'Reprovado'
END}"

) search_values` ?

Comment: I suppose that `search_values` is the argument to your `.search()` method, so you should put it in the correct place. **BUT** if the search does not go to the database (for instance you are using a search server), then sorting won't help. You'd need to add the translated field to the search index, so the search server will return the matches already sorted.